# Inject a service into another service

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, dart

I would like to inject a service into another service but, for some reason, the "@Inject" decorator is being ignored. For example, the following service depends on another service:

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
    final AnotherService _service;
    MyService(@Inject(AnotherService) this._service);
// ... more methods
}
```

Angular2 throws the following error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for AnotherService!

Am I using the "@Inject" decorator in a bad way?

Comment: Have you imported `import { Inject } from 'angular2/core';`?

Comment: The exception imply he did...  it's an angular exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some information is missing to fully solve this but exception says that the injector doesn't have enough information to resolve **AnotherService**

The DI in angular is build upon hierarchies, starting from the root injector which is created upon an angular application bootstrap.

Each hierarchy is a new injector instance, resolving a dependency is done from bottom to top, i.e: if an injector can't resolve it will ask its parent to resolve. This will go on until it reach an injector without a parent (root injector).

Make sure you declare a provider for AnotherService before you declare a provider for MyService.

Just add a provider to AnotherService in the providers array you supply to bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was what I suspected. I wonder what is the purpose of the @Inject() directive, since it can be omitted and it does nothing.

Comment: The `@Inject` decorator allows (among other things) injection of string tokens (opposed to type tokens), see OpaqueToken.

Also note that when you declare `@Injectable` on a class you tell tell the Injector that this class can be injected, making the `@Inject` redundant for Typed Tokens (you still need it for String tokens)