# Angular Inject Service into Service : No Provider

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two services in Angular:

`MonitoringService.service.ts`:

```
import { ClientAppSettingService } from './clientAppSettings.service';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService
{
  constructor(private _clientAppSettingService: ClientAppSettingService)
  {
    this.getclientAppSettings();
  }
  getclientAppSettings(): any {
    this._clientAppSettingService.getConfig().subscribe(result => {
    this.data = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

and `ClientAppSetting.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettingsClient } from '../models/appSettingsClient';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ClientAppSettingService {
  appUrl: string = "";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.appUrl = baseUrl;
  }
  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get<AppSettingsClient>(this.appUrl + 'api/ClientAppSettings/Get');
  }
}
```

This is `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientAppSettingService } from './services/clientAppSettings.service';
import { HomeService } from './services/home.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MonitoringService } from './services/monitoring.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { EmbedReportComponent } from './embedReport/embedReport.component';
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    EmbedReportComponent,
    BaseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'report', component: EmbedReportComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    ClientAppSettingService,
    HomeService,
    ReportService,
    MonitoringService
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152608/angular-2-inject-service-to-another-service-no-provider-error) , which says that you need to provide service in the provider of `NgModule`.

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295702/inject-a-service-into-another-service), which says

> Make sure you declare a provider for ClientAppSettingService before you declare
>   a provider for MonitorningService

I also tried adding @Inject in my constructor as below:

```
constructor( @Inject(ClientAppSettingService) _clientAppSettingService: ClientAppSettingService)
```

However, I still receive error regarding No Provider:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ClientAppSettingService! (MonitoringService -> ClientAppSettingService)
>   Error: No provider for ClientAppSettingService! (MonitoringService -> ClientAppSettingService)

**Additional Information:**

I have a `base.component.ts` which calls the MonitoringService:

```
import { MonitoringService } from './services/monitoring.service';
import { Component, ReflectiveInjector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class BaseComponent
{
  constructor(private _monitoringService: MonitoringService)
  {
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      MonitoringService
    ]);
    this._monitoringService = injector.get(MonitoringService);
  }
```

Then I extent other components with `Base.component.ts` to use the MonitorningService as below. For example `home.component.ts` uses MonitoringService as below:

```
import { Home } from '../models/home';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base.component';
import { MonitoringService } from '../services/monitoring.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit
{
  home: Home;

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private _monitorningService: MonitoringService)
  {
    super(_monitorningService);
  }
```

Comment: can you post whole code for app.module.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan I updated the question with app.module.ts

Comment: You must `provide` a singleton service even for injecting into other services. So since you cannot provide to a service you must `provide` to the nearest module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain it a little.
You have two layers one layer is your component and the other layer is your module.
What you can do is provide the ClientAppSettingService into the component:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ClientAppSettingService]
})
```

You have to remove it from your module and keep the other one there.
Keep in mind that everywhere where you want to inject your service you have to provide it into the component.

Comment: Can you please provide your answer with an example? Especially, how the  MonitoringService looks like when trying to call method of the ClientAppSettingService.

Comment: The same as you do above.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have not registered your Service in app.module.ts file. You need to set ClientAppSettingService into providers array in app.module.ts. it should look like

```
providers: [ClientAppSettingService]
```

of course you will have to import the same before using it into providers array.

Comment: This is already there. I have this added to providers section of app.module.ts