# How to inject a service into another service and use it within exported constants or interfaces in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, typescript-typings, angular-components

I would like to inject a service into another service with which I want to translate strings within exported constants.

My code currently looks like this (I've simplified it here)

```
// Imports..

@Injectable(
  { providedIn: 'root' }
)
export class MyService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private injectedService: InjectedService) {
  }

  // Methods..
}

export enum Series {
  prop_1 = 'String_1',
  prop_2 = 'String_2',
  prop_3 = 'String_3',
}

export const ALL_SERIES: Series[] = [
  this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
  this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
  this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
];
```

However, I get this error because the injected service is not detected outside the component:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'injectedService' of undefined

What would be the cleanest solution to this problem?

Comment: the type for injectedService is not mentioned in the constructor the way it is mentioned for httpClient, if the type for injectedService will be mentioned then angular would know what type to use for DI

Comment: @manishgdev I'm sorry, I forgot it in my simplified version. Still does not work..

Comment: doesn't makes sense to inject a service inside another service if you want to use it outside the service........................

Comment: @PedroB. That's exactly my question. How could I proceed here?

Comment: may be this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131894/angular-inject-service-into-service-no-provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a `getSeries` method in the service that will return the values of the constant. `This` will be defined inside the `MyService` class and thus no error.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private injectedService: InjectedService) {}

  // Methods..

  getSeries(): Series[] {
    return [
      this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
      this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
      this.injectedService.translate(Series.prop_1),
    ];
  }
}

export enum Series {
  prop_1 = 'String_1',
    prop_2 = 'String_2',
    prop_3 = 'String_3',
}
```

Instead of `ALL_SERIES` you would have to call `getSeries()` method though.